# Check if string contains a number or a special character

Tags: validation-rule, regular-expressions

Regex newbie here, I'm trying to create a validation rule which will restrict users from entering a number or a special characters to a certain field.

This is what I have so far:

```
!IsNew() && REGEX(Origin__c, '[!@#$%^&*(),.?":{}|<>0-9]')
```

However, it does not work as I'm still able to insert inputs such as:
'abc123' or 'abc@df'

I checked the regex expression in regextester.com and it worked, it detected what I needed, but in SF it didn't, so what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like this.

```
!IsNew() && NOT(REGEX(Origin__c, "^[a-z A-Z]*$"))
```